# Does UdpClient need a StreamReader?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, sockets, udp

So with TCPClient and SerialPort, I am using a streamreader to pull in lines of data. Rather than manually dealing with the the pieces of data coming into buffer, I let the streamreader handle it. TcpClient has a [GetStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient_methods(v=vs.110).aspx) method, and [SerialPort](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport(v=vs.110).aspx) seems to use a BaseStream with their ReadLine method. The [UdpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient(v=vs.110).aspx) however does not have a stream associated with it.

I am to assume that the [UdpClient.Receive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient.receive(v=vs.110).aspx) method is returning 1 line of data from the buffer? Or will it be sending chunks of data with line feeds possibly in the middle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contrary to TCP, UDP deals with messages (datagrams). One sent message equals zero or more equal messages received.

In other words: what you send is what you might get out, exactly as you sent it.

Comment: So basically I can assume the linefeed will be at the end of each datagram?

Comment: I don't know, that depends on what you send, which you didn't show.

Comment: There will be a linefeed if you send a linefeed. If you don't send a linefeed there won't be one.

Comment: Right so if I am receiving 100 messages per second, each one of them with a line feed on the end, then each message returned from the UdpClient.Receive will have a line feed on the end.